# how to call and execute MySQL commands programmatically?

Tags: c#, mysql, cmd

I want to run all commands programmatically and the commands are like:

```
string mysql ="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin"
string command =" mysql.exe -u root -ppassword fabrica < c:/backup.sql";
```

I want to run these two lines using C#, how can I achieve this?

Comment: yes process.start("cmd") and how to run these also ?

Comment: put them in a batch file, and run it.

Comment: Process.Start("cmd", "/c "+"\"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql.exe\""+" -u root -ppassword fabrica < c:/backup.sql")

Comment: May I suggest, CLI may not be the most productive way to interact with your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDITED : Now i know what you want to do exactly

Here is a code to make it in a method

```
string binary = @"C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqldump.exe"
string arguments = @"-uroot -ppassword sample"
ProcessStartInfo PSI = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(binary, arguments);
PSI.RedirectStandardInput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
PSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(PSI);
Encoding encoding = p.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding;
System.IO.StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(@"c:\backup.sql", false, encoding);
p.WaitOnExit();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
SW.Write(output)
SW.Close();
```

Good luck!

Comment: this line not executing pr.StartInfo.Arguments = @"mysql.exe -u root -ppassword fabrica < c:/backup.sql";

Comment: no any exception . after executing this command prompt stop on "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin"; next line not executing

Comment: do you want to dump a MySQL database? using c#

Comment: and dump backup i think we cant restore using Msql application